# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, connection-pooling

I recently deployed a working webapp on my localhost to amazon web services.
The problem i'm encountering is - though context.xml has username as 'james', the exception stacktrace mentions otherwise.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:491)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

It is trying to connect to database with username 'root'. It it be because of caching of the file(context.xml)? How do I tackle that? I have restarted the web server as well, but it's not coming to effect.

Thanks in Advance.

`EDIT:`

Here's the content of context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
    <Resource 
       name="jdbc/NetmarketDB"
       auth="Container"
       type="javax.sql.DataSource"
       removeAbandoned="true"
       removeAbandonedTimeout="30"
       maxActive="100"
       maxIdle="30"
       maxWait="1000"
       username="james"
       password="xxxxxxxxxx"
       driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
       url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ams"/>
</Context>
```

You can see it happening by clicking on `Login` or `Register` on the page:
http://184.73.118.76/Links.jsp

Is there anything I need to do to bring context.xml changes to effect?
I have carried out two actions:
1. `touch web.xml` in WEB-INF
2. Restart tomcat server.

Desperately need help here.

Thanks again.
James.

Comment: This looks pretty much like an MySQL Error. I guess you need to configure your mysql server to accept root login from localhost, or better: setup a proper user!

Comment: MySQL Error? I don't think so. If it was mysql error, why would it try to login with 'root' instead of 'james' as mentioned in context.xml?  

'james' is a proper user. Even if we change username to 'root', it still won't work because the cached(i strongly believe this to be the reason) file might have some value for password, which wouldn't match 
with the actual root database password.

Comment: can you post the dbcp configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Check your $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/[webapp].xml, on default Tomcat this should be $CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/[webapp].xml, tomcat create a copy of your context.xml and this probably was not updated when you update your context.xml

[Tomcat Context Container Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html)

> $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/, in an individual file at
>   /META-INF/context.xml inside the application files. If the web
>   application is packaged as a WAR then /META-INF/context.xml will be
>   copied to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ and renamed to
>   match the application's context path. Once this file exists, it will
>   not be replaced if a new WAR with a newer /META-INF/context.xml is
>   placed in the host's appBase.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there isn't a file named $CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/yourapp.xml or that it doesn't contain another datasource definition to the same database with the username 'james'.